# From binary to string

Tags: arrays, c, string, multidimensional-array, binary

I have to convert the binary to string, I tried something, but it didn't work.

This is my code (I don't allowed to change the main function!) , but I can't understand what's wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

void decode_bytes(const int rows, bool bytes[rows][8], char string[rows]){
    int iteration = 8;

    for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < iteration; i++){
            if (bytes[j][i] == 1){
                string[j] += pow(2, iteration - (i + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
bool bytes2[7][8] = {
    {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
    {0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1},
    {0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0},
    {0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0},
    {0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1},
    {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};
char string[7];
decode_bytes(7, bytes2, string);
printf("%s\n", string);
}
```

Output must be: "hello", but it's "cel<mB"....

Comment: In the future, do not put the arbitrary "can someone please help me with my code?" it turns people away, you should edit that out.

Comment: For starters, don't use `pow` to calculate powers of integers. Floating point math is not precise. In the particular case of binary numbers, you can use bit-shifting to calculate powers of 2.

Comment: What is the problem? Please [edit] and show some input along with expected vs actual output. Also never use `pow` for integer problems, there are simpler and more reliable ways to calculate a power of 2.

Comment: Please specify exactly what are the inputs and the expected outputs.

Comment: Where is the nul-terminator which is required for the string in `printf("%s\n", string);`? It would need `char string[7];` to be `char string[8];` too.

Comment: You have `string[j] += ` but `string` has not been initialised.